# "inotifywait -e close_write" not triggering even when tail shows new lines

Tags: bash, inotify

I have a script:

```
nohup tail -f /somefile >> /soemeotherfile.dat &
nohup while inotifywait -e close_write /someotherfile.dat; do ./script.sh; done &
```

but it seems that script.sh is never activated despite input arriving at the tail of /somefile every 5 minutes. What is wrong with my script above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `inotifywait` docs:

> - `close_write`
>
>   A watched file or a file within a watched directory was closed, after being opened in writeable mode. This does not necessarily imply the file was written to.

`close_write` only triggers when a file is *closed* (which is typically desirable: it reduces the chances of trying to read content while it's in a half-written state).

---

```
tail -f /somefile >> /soemeotherfile.dat
```

...continually appends to `someotherfile.dat`. It *does not* close it after each individual write.

Probably you want the `modify` event instead.

Comment: I think the confusion comes watching a directory with the `--include` option. vs watching specific file(s).

Use `close_write` for the former but `modify` for the latter.